# Galois cohomology of a non-abelian group over a function field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, etale-cohomology, galois-cohomology

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and $X$ a connected smooth projective curve over $X$. Let $F$ be the function field of $k$. Let $G$ be an algebraic group over $k$ (assume that it is smooth, or reductive, if needed). Can you explain why $H^1 (Gal(F^{sep}/F) , G(F^{sep}))$ is zero, or provide a simple reference?

Thank you,
Sasha

Comment: Do you mean $G(\overline{F})$?

Comment: Another typo is "over $X$" should be "over $k$".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to assume that $G$ is connected or else that is false.  Assuming that $G$ is connected, this follows immediately from Steinberg's Theorem, i.e., the proof of Serre's Conjecture I.  There is a copy of Steinberg's paper as an appendix of Serre's book on Galois Cohomology.  Serre explains in the book how to deduce your statement from Steinberg's Theorem. Also Qiaochu Yuan is correct; you should use $G(\overline{F})$, not $G(F)$.  Finally, since Galois cohomology is insensitive to nilpotents in $G$, you immediately reduce to the case that $G$ is smooth and connected.

Comment: Strictly speaking, if ${\rm{char}}(k)>0$ then: it is better to write $F_s$ than $\overline{F}$, many non-split connected unipotent linear algebraic $F$-groups have H$^1\ne 1$, and $G_{\rm{red}}$ can fail to be an $F$-subgroup scheme (so not $F$-smooth) even if $G$ is connected (SGA3, VI$_{\rm{A}}$, 1.3.2). A minor point: Steinberg's 1965 paper is written for a perfect ground field (but it works as written without perfectness once one has a sufficiently robust theory of reductive groups over general fields, as Steinberg noted in his paper had been done by Grothendieck at that time).

Comment: @nfdc23.  Since the OP stated that $G$ is defined over an algebraically closed field, I decided against raising all of your (legitimate) points.  Serre does also have a follow-up paper, "Cohomologie galoisienne, progres et problemes" (... I cannot make French accents in comments ! ...) where he speculates on the correct formulation over non-perfect fields (but with a condition on the p-rank).

Comment: @JasonStarr:  Ah, I had not noticed that $G$ is given over $k$ and rather than "just" over $F$.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Do I understand correctly, that if $G$ is a connected split(!) reductive group over $F$, then its first Galois cohomology will be zero, where $F$ is completely arbitrary? Because it seems the dimension 1 hypothesis is only needed to deal with non-split tori. Or perhaps I didn't understand something correctly.

Comment: @Sasha. "Do I understand correctly, that if $G$ is a connected split(!) reductive group over $F$, then its first Galois cohomology will be zero, where $F$ is completely arbitrary?"  That is not correct.  Already the Hamilton Quaternions give a nontrivial element of $H^1_{\text{Gal}}(\mathbb{R},\textbf{PGL}_2)$.  Steinberg proves that torsors reduce to tori, but he does not prove that they reduce to split tori (so you do not get to use Hilbert's Theorem 90).

Comment: @JasonStarr: Thank you, I will think about that.

Comment: @Sasha. Just to make that a little less cryptic:  Steinberg's theorem proves that every $G$-torsor over $F$ reduces to a maximal subtorus of the linear algebraic group over $F$, $G\times_{\text{Spec}(k)}\text{Spec}(F)$.  Some such tori are of the form $T\times_{\text{Spec}(k)}\text{Spec}(F)$; these are split tori.  However, there are also non-split maximal tori in $G\times_{\text{Spec}(k)}\text{Spec}(F)$.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Thank you! This helped indeed to isolate the point of non-understanding.